# UIImage the same size as her UIImageView but not shown equal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

In my code, I make this:

```
imageFormatos = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FondoFormatos"];
formatosImageView.frame = CGRectMake(tempFormatoX, 540, widthFormato, 230);
    formatosImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    formatosImageView.layer.borderWidth=0.0;
    [imageFormatos DrawInRect:CGRectMake(formatosImageView.frame.origin.x,formatosImageView.frame.origin.y,formatosImageView.frame.size.width,formatosImageView.frame.size.height)];
formatosImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

And shown like this:

[image]

I set background to see the size of 2 views. I need the black image fill all imageView.

Edit: Ok, it have transparent bounds, but in Xcode file inspector not shown:

[image]

Comment: Can you check by opening image in preview and please check is there any transparent background around your image?

Comment: formatosImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; try this once

Answer (score 0):

```
imageFormatos = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FondoFormatos"];
formatosImageView.frame = CGRectMake(tempFormatoX, 540, widthFormato, 230);
    formatosImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    formatosImageView.layer.borderWidth=0.0;
 self.formatosImageView.image= imageFormatos;

formatosImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

I have updated your code, check once

Comment: Once add another image and check once.I think the image has transparent edges